Query errors sometimes occur in API using Spring WebFlux and Kotlin
controller - (https://i.sstatic.net/UGwRz.png)
 @GetMapping("/id")
 suspend fun checkId(@RequestParam siteId: String) : ResponseEntity<String> {
   return agentService.checkId(siteId)
 }

service - (https://i.sstatic.net/wmTfM.png)
suspend fun checkId(siteId : String) : CheckIdResponse {
  agentRepository.findTop1BySiteId(siteId)?.let {
    return CheckIdResponse(
      result = false
    )
  }
  return CheckIdResponse(
    result = true
  )
}

repository - (https://i.sstatic.net/cmKd4.png)
@Repository
interface AgentRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<Agent, String> 
{
 suspend fun findTop1BySiteId(siteId: String) : Agent?
}

entity - (https://i.sstatic.net/e2e1B.png)
@Table
data class Agent(
  @Id
  @Column("idx")
  var id: Int? = null,

  @Column("agentid")
  val agentId: String,

  @Column("agentpw")
  val agentPw: String? = null,

  @Column("agentname")
  val agentName: String? = null,
)

After deploy, it works properly for about an hour or two, but suddenly a query error occurs.
What should I do in this case?
error cause = Call another repository function
(https://i.sstatic.net/3hZOe.png)
error syntax = Parameterized query requires parameter, but was not provided.
I changed CoroutineCrudRepository to ReactiveCrudRepository. but it didn't work.
